# kivy not working with kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I defined CustomButton and CustomWidget in custom.kv file, 
defined empty CustomWidget class in main.py, but when I run the program, window is all black, there is no button. What am I doing wrong?

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class CustomWidget(Widget):
    pass

class CustomButton(Button):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
            return CustomWidget()


application = MyApp()
application.run()
```

custom.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<CustomButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: .5, .5, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'background.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

<CustomWidget>:
    CustomButton:
        text: 'Random'
        pos: root.x, 200
```

output:

[image: black window]

Comment: Change the name of your `.kv` file to `my.kv`. See [Documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html).

Comment: @John thank you so much! it works now :D